# Â - cause for these strange characters

Tags: php, html

In my php application i am inserting images, where i save the image path in my mysql database and the images in the folder. When i save the image my image file name gets added with **Â**.

For Example:
Actual image name is `40375-sales report template-Sales-plan`
When i submit the image the filename gets added up with this strange character (`Â`) such as `40375-sales report template-Sales-planÂ`.

I am not sure why do i face this issue. please help me out

Comment: You'll need to show some code on how you fetch the name, how you insert it, and try to debug this by dumping the values before insertion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it comes from PHP which connects to mysql with different kind of encoding.

Maybe set names to UTF8.

Hopefully it will solve your issue.